# Pubnub.getMessageEventNameFor() doesn't trigger

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pubnub

I've spent days to figure this out but I don't understand the problem, to start here's Pubnub codes in the relatives files:

**File 1)** where event *doesn't* trigger:

```
this.$rootScope.$on(this.Pubnub.getMessageEventNameFor("activity_" + this.activity.id + "_tables"), function (ngEvent, envelope) {
        console.log("envelope", envelope);
    });
```

**File 2)** (It's a copy of file 1) where event trigger (just changed the channel name):

```
this.$rootScope.$on(this.Pubnub.getMessageEventNameFor("kitchen_" + this.activity.id + "_tables"), function (ngEvent, envelope) {
                console.log("envelope", envelope);
            });
```

**File 3)** that fires the event:

```
this.Pubnub.publish({
            channel: "kitchen_" + sessionStorage.getItem('activity_id') + "_tables",
            message: angular.toJson({ msg: "New Table", table: new_table})
        }, function (status, response) {
        });

this.Pubnub.publish({
            channel: "activity_" + sessionStorage.getItem('activity_id') + "_tables",
            message: angular.toJson({ msg: "New Table", table: new_table})
        }, function (status, response) {
        });
```

- The **activity.id** it's the same for all (tested)
- I've made a console.log(this.$rootScope) in **File 1** and the event exist:

> .$$listeners["pubnub:default:subscribe:callback:activity_SUyNTii1He_tables"]["0"]

(If I pass the mouse over I can see the body of the function and if I click "Show Function Definition" it takes me to the function, so it has the function)

- When I fire the event from **File 3**... In **File 1** there's only a console print line:

> pubnub.4.3.3.js:1670 XHR finished loading: GET "http://ps1.pubnub.com/v2/subscribe/MY_KEY_AND_UUID&pnsdk=PubNub-JS-Web%2F4.3.3".

And if I click to open the link in a New Tab it show me the right JSON structure containing all my data passed from **File 3**:

```
{
"t": {
    "t": "14970265478466724",
    "r": 12
},
"m": [
    {
        "a": "0",
        "f": 0,
        "i": "...other-key...",
        "p": {
            "t": "14970265478474153",
            "r": 12
        },
        "k": "...subscribe-key...",
        "c": "activity_SUyNTii1He_tables",
        "d": "{
            ...all my data...
        }",
        "b": "activity_SUyNTii1He_tables"
    }
]
```

}

I don't have much knowledge about Pubnub, so I don't know if I miss something from it...

**UPDATE**
I have fixed the problem. In my "page" of the File 2 there are two tags that complete my html page, each tag is a file from "component" and each file had a Pubnub Initialization. Having two initialization on the same "page" create this problem, so removing one (i have removed Pubnub Initialization in **File 2**) will resolve this problem.
Maybe it's usefull for future this problem. It was a mistake of logic in Angular that I didn't think of these 2 Components file like one in a Page file

Answer (score 1):

Did you register the event?
For eg:

```
Pubnub.subscribe({
    channel: $scope.channel, 
    triggerEvents: ['event1', 'event2', 'event3', '...']
});
```

Comment: No but I've found a solution, there was a problem with Pubnub Initialization (on File 2 there were two items connected, both had Pubnub initialization so I've cancelled one and now it's all fine)

Answer (score 0):

Op's solution didn't work for me, but i managed the problem by changing the `channel` property on subscribe to an array with the selected channel.

ex.:

```
Pubnub.subscribe({
    channels: [ $scope.channel ],
    triggerEvents: true
});
```

https://github.com/pubnub/pubnub-angular#events

Hope it helps someone.